# DataGridView Resizing for anchor

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a form with a DataGridView on it.
By default the datagridview should take up as much height as it can.
I use the anchor bottom to do this.

At the bottom of the form I have a button called "expand".
When clicked it will open a panel and this resize's the datagridview so that
the panel can fit on the form.

When the panel is expanded the "expand" button is not visible anymore and a new button appears within the newly visible panel, called "minimize".
When this minimize button is clicked the panel is collapsed and the datagridview should resize to fill the form vertically again.

Currently this works but the issue is at startup I cannot get the datagridview to fill the form vertically on startup, only when I click the buttons.

**Image 1:**
[image]
[Full size image 1](https://s18.postimg.org/7nxvadwu1/image.png)

**Image 2:**
[image]
[Full size image 2](https://s9.postimg.org/ullys7ren/image.png)

**Image 3:**
[image]
[Full size image 3](https://s18.postimg.org/4q5hufek9/image.png)

So basically when the program starts I want the datagridview to be fully expanded vertically.

The hide button does:

```
this.splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = true;
this.expandBtn.Visible = true;
```

The expand button does:

```
this.splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = false;
this.expandBtn.Visible = false;
```

DataGridView anchor: Top, Bottom,Left.

Answer (score 0):

On startup, you need to set

```
splitContainer1.Panel2MinSize = 0; //I assumed that the Panal2 contains bottom panel for log as you show in screen shots
//and then
this.splitContainer1.Panel2Collapsed = true;
```

Comment: No good, it stays the default size on startup, it only fills the screen when the expand button is clicked and then the minimize button is clicked.

Comment: @Steve Is your grid dock to the panel?

Comment: @Steve When you set `Panel2MinSize = 0` then that panel will be collapsed completely and other panel will be filled on whole `SplitterContainer`.